# Bash autocompletion for pake WITH local files

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I am using bash autocompletion for pake

```
_pake()
{
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(/www/grepo/vendor/bin/pake tasklist)" -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _pake pake
```

That works fine for all pake tasks, but how do I now add completion for my file system in addition to the task list?

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply to that question as a message. The solution is quite easy, you can add a fallback behaviour to complete

```
complete -o default -F _pake pake
```

Given that, the auto complete behaviour falls bask to shell default if the custom completion does not deliver results